# UrlRoutingModule is missing from IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, url-routing, iis-7.5

I am setting up a new server, and the "UrlRoutingModule-4.0" module is missing form IIS.  I installed the MVC3 Update before installing IIS.  Realizing my mistake, I uninstalled MVC3, and installed IIS 7 with all of the "Application Development" roles: ASP.NET, .NET Extensibility, ASP, etc...

Now, when I install MVC3 (AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup), and I check IIS, the "UrlRoutingModule-4.0" module is not present.  Obviously my MVC3 application does not work.  I just get 404s whenever I try to request a controller.

Did I mess up by installing MVC3 before IIS was landed?  How can I fix this box?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try running the following command to see if it fixes the problem:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

That should re-install .NET 4 with IIS, in case you installed them in the wrong order.